# Tabbing between links causes issues with pseudo-elements in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, pseudo-element, clearfix

In Chrome, click in the results pane and hit tab to focus on the first link here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2q6c7c36/2/

notice how the contents of .box "jump up" outside of its border? It appears to be caused by the clearfix class I'm using. Is this a bug in Chrome or something I'm doing wrong? I've noticed it when using pseudo elements for icon fonts as well.

Thanks.

```
.clearfix:after{
    content: ".";
    visibility: hidden;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/2q6c7c36/3/

set the `content:"."` to `content:""`

```css
.box {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 318px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #555;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: helvetica;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box clearfix">
  <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
  <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
  <a href="#" class="button">Button</a>
</div>
```